# Why is the Haar measure of a Lie group with finite abelianization both left and right translation invariant? (Moved from math.SE)

Tags: lie-groups, measure-theory

I'm reading *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds* by Ratcliffe. On the way to proving Gromov's theorem on the proportionality of hyperbolic volume and simplicial volume, he states that "it is a basic fact of the theory of Haar measure that the Haar measure on a group is both left- and right-invariant if the abelianization of the group is finite." Why should this be?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#The_modular_function

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The modular quasicharacter (quotient of left and right haar measures) is a group homomorphism from G to the positive reals (under multiplication). This obviously factors through the abelianisation since the target is abelian, and there are no homomorphisms from a finite abelian group to the positive reals.

Comment: There are no *nontrivial* homomorphims from a finite group to the reals.